# calculate different combination of numbers with different number of columns in C++?

Tags: c++, math, boost, statistics

I would really appreciate it if someone can point me to the right direction with this problem. I am trying to find all the different combinations of various numbers each with a different number of columns (in C++). for example consider the number 2:

two columns:

2 = { 2 , 0 }
     { 0 , 2 }
     { 1 , 1 }

three columns :

2 = { 0 , 0 , 2 }
    { 0 , 2 , 0 }
    { 2 , 0 , 0 }
    { 1 , 1 , 0 }
    { 0 , 1 , 1 }
    { 1 , 0 , 1 }

four columns:

2 = { 0 , 0 , 0 , 2 }
    { 0 , 0 , 2 , 0 }
    { 0 , 2 , 0 , 0 }
    { 2 , 0 , 0 , 0 }
    { 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 }
    { 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 }
    { 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 }
    { 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 }
    { 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 }
    { 0 , 1 , 0 , 1 }

thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just so much university homework I can't force myself to think otherwise.

Comment: you might be surprised to hear this but this is not a university question

Comment: Anyway, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient. It might help

Comment: Do you want to print them, or just find the number of combinations?

Comment: it would be great to print them please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```
void combinations(int n, int columns, std::vector<int>& soFar)
{
    if (columns == 1)
    {
        for (auto e : soFar)
            std::cout << e << " ";
        std::cout << n << '\n';
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        soFar.push_back(i);
        combinations(n - i, columns - 1, soFar);
        soFar.pop_back();
    }
}

void combinations(int n, int columns)
{
    std::vector<int> soFar;
    combinations(n, columns, soFar);
}
```

Basically, you keep dividing the number into two subparts, till you reach your depth limit (the number of columns in your case).
To keep printing the previous numbers on the way back up, I store them in the `soFar` vector, pushing and popping them accordingly.

Here's the output for `combinations(2, 4)`:

```
0 0 0 2
0 0 1 1
0 0 2 0
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
0 2 0 0
1 0 0 1
1 0 1 0
1 1 0 0
2 0 0 0
```

Comment: you know i looked at this in amazement, i have written code on my own which does similar but no way near as efficient as this, i am very impressed

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting the problem into two subproblems:

1) Find all the combinations of numbers that add to your number:

i.e: 2-column case for "3": (2,1) and (3,0)

2) Permute all the combinations you've found:

i.e: (2,1) -> (2,1), (1,2) and (3,0) -> (3,0), (0,3)

---

For part 1), you get the problem of big numbers and many columns, say  5 with 4 columns (i know, they're unfathomably huge numbers):

5 = 4 + 1

5 = 3 + 2

5 = 3 + 1 + 1

5 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1

5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1  + 1

If you look carefully, you have a possibility for recursion. As in, for 5 = 3 + 2: find the combinations for 3 and the combinations for 2 and so on... until you get to 1

As soon as you say recursion, tree structures start to sound interesting. This is how I'd approach the problem.

Comment: interesting, what makes this difficult is the idea of adding any number of columns

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight combinatorics question. If you have m columns, then you have m-1 dividers between columns. With the number n, you want all the ways to order m-1 dividers and n elements. For example, with n=5 and m=3, one possible arrangement is xx,x,xx -- and you are looking at 7 choose 2.

So the general solution is m+n-1 choose m-1, or equivalently, m+n-1 choose n.

The formula for x choose y is x! / [y! * (x-y)!]

Comment: i have just tested this, it does not quite do what i want